# Automatically lock cursor movement and keyboard once video starts playing in browser?

Tags: video, keyboard, mouse

Here is an use case scenario-:

An user opens youtube.com. Then searches "xyz" and starts watching a video about xyz. Now the user can't use his mouse. Preferably, I'd want that the user can't use his keyboard except 3 keys. The 3 keys are space, left and right. Once the video finishes, then automatically the cursor and keyboard gets unlocked again. This will help a lot to a "distracted user". And will definitely improve productivity and learning.

It's windows platform

It'd be great if same tool works for udemy(or any video platform) as well.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I'm not sure that this isn't a spam for udemy.

Answer (score 1):

Buy a Stack Overflow keyboard - https://stackoverflow.blog/2021/03/31/the-key-copy-paste/ [this was originally an April Fool's joke, but has since been made for real].

Use [AutoHotKey](https://www.autohotkey.com) or [Karabiner-Elements](https://karabiner-elements.pqrs.org) [you didn't tell us what platform you're on] to map the three keys as you wish.

Take the original keyboard & mouse away.

[image]

Comment: i don't think that's gonna help man. i'll look at it. this is not very hard to do. it's just copying and pasting commands, but i'm not sure how to do it as i've never coded in my life. i wonder in this world of self help and productivity, how this product was never made.

Comment: Probably because this isn't really a productivity issue, it's one of self-control. Play the video fullscreen, leave the keyboard alone.